# Regex to search for a pattern and replace the pattern and sub-string preceding it

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am new to python. I have a `string` from which I would like to select pattern `false` and the characters preceding it until hyphen with some other string if required.

Example:

```
string = -I false -n 0 -i false -X false -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0 --no-partial-observations false -u false
```

Result string should be like this:

```
string = -n 0 -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0
```

I use `re` method to replace false with another character but could not get what I wanted.

Comment: *I use "re" method to replace false with another character but could not get what I wanted*? Can you add your sample code, perhaps we can help debug it. See how to add a [MCVE]

Comment: `>>>import re
>>> string = "-I false -n 0 -i false -X false -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0 --no-partial-observations false -u false"
>>> string = re.sub("false", '', string)
>>> string
'-I  -n 0 -i  -X  -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0 --no-partial-observations  -u '`

Comment: Thanks Bhargav, I just used the above code of re.sub but it just removed the substring "false" but I also wanted to replace the 2 substrings preceding false

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> string = "-I false -n 0 -i false -X false -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0 --no-partial-observations false -u false"
>>> 
>>> string = re.sub(r"-{1,2}[\w-]+\s+false\s?", "", string)
>>> 
>>> string
'-n 0 -E 0 --min-repeat-size 5 --min-repeat-entropy 0 '
>>>
```